# My TempArray always has the wrong values and therefore doesnt evaluate properly and I am confused why

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-logic

I am writing a program to evaluate a boolean algebra equation such as A'B + C'

Ive tried changing how the temparray is read or created and im not sure what im missing

Im relativey new to this so it might be very obvious and thanks for any help

Is it a problem with how im assigning values to the tempArray? because the regular array works just fine, i need the temp array so it can take the terms between the + and evaluate them first then evaluate the + after

my input is `6` and then `A'B+C'` where `'` is negate of the previous variable and it gives me

```
RESULT IN EVAL TERM FUNCTION: 1
Term Result: 1
REAL ARRAY
A'B+C'

TEMP ARRAY
 ☺ ' ☺ 2   ⌂
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


bool evalTerm(int A, int B, int C, char *term);


int main() {
    int s;
    int A = true;
    int B = true;
    int C = true;


    printf("Enter The Length of Your Function: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    char arr[s + 1];

    printf("Enter a sum-of-products: ");

    scanf("%s", arr);

char tempArray[s+1];

    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(arr); i++) {
        if (arr[i] == '+' || arr[i] == '\0'){
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
                if (arr[j] == 'A') {
                    tempArray[j] = A;

                }
                if (arr[j] == 'B') {
                    tempArray[j] = B;

                }

                if (arr[j] == 'C') {
                    tempArray[j] = C;

                }

                if (arr[j] == '\'') {
                    tempArray[j] = '\'';

                }
            }
            bool termResult = evalTerm(A,B,C,tempArray);
            printf("Term Result: %d\n", termResult);


        }

    }
//get everything before first + and copy it to tep array, then evaluate and put in result array then get next terms and then OR result array at end




    printf("REAL ARRAY\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("TEMP ARRAY\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        printf(" %c", tempArray[i]);
    }


}


bool evalTerm(int A, int B, int C, char *term){


    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(term); i++) {
        if (term[i] == '\'') {
            switch (term[i - 1]) {
                case 'A':
                    A = !A;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    B = !B;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    C = !C;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    bool result = A && B && C;
    printf("RESULT IN EVAL TERM FUNCTION: %d\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the input that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: the one ive been using to test is length of 6 and A'B+C' which should evaluate to false because false and true + false should be false right?

Comment: Edit the question to show the exact text of input that reproduces the problem, the exact text of the observed output, and the text of the output that is desired instead.

Comment: @EricPostpischil just added the edit

Comment: `tempArray[j] = A` assigns the integer value 1 (true) to that array index. `evalTerm` is looking for a character like `'A'`. They will never match up. `printf(" %c", tempArray[i]);` assumes that `tempArray` contains printable characters but other than possibly `'\''` it will not.

Comment: <O/T> prompting the user to enter the length of the function is weird, just do `char arr[256];` or something "big enough" for what you're trying to do here. `scanf` needs additional protection to ensure you don't overflow `arr` anyway. Computers these days have bukos of memory, managing down to the exact bytes you need here in this case is not worth the effort (if you're on some highly constrained embedded system then nevermind).

Comment: Your program is nowhere near ready to work. I started to write up an analysis, but the program is just utterly broken. If you want to evaluate the formula by using `tempArray` to hold numerical values where `arr` holds variable names, then you need to start by filling in all those values into `tempArray`. Then, when you evaluate them, you need to change them in place in `tempArray`, not by changing the original variables as `evalTerm` does with `'\''`…

Comment: …  And you need some way to evaluate the products that appear in `tempArray` instead of its hard-coded `A && B && C`, and then you have to evaluate the sums. That will be troublesome since evaluating the products reduces the number of operands (each product replaces two operands with one), so you need to either move things around in `tempArray` or somehow remember which operands have been reduced. You should entirely reconsider the approach to parsing and evaluation.